# Json.NET Serializing / Deserializing Array of Datetimes with Custom Format

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to apply a custom datetime format to an array of datetime values. I know you can use IsoDateTimeConverter to accomplish this for single values e.g.

```
class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}

class ReturnObjectA 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set;}
}
```

But how do apply the same thing to an array of datetimes? e.g. The following does not work.

```
class ReturnObjectA 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime[] ReturnDate { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) is what you're looking for:

```
class ReturnObjectA
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime[] ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```